# Angular 6 Nav tab is not active when I click the hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hyperlink, angular6

I have created a routing example in angular [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dqxeg3). The output of the routing example looks like as shown below.

[image]

When I click the **Players** tab, the table is made active, but when I click the **View Players** and **View Players (Script)** hyperlinks inside Dashboard tab then it navigates to Players tab but the tab is not active (active class is not added to the tab)  like as shown below

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've set the exact route to true and the routerLink inside it wasn't directing to the main *players* route.

```
<li [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }" routerLinkActive="active">
  <a [routerLink]="['/players']">Players</a>
</li>
```